# Issue processing incoming emails in mailgun

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I want to process the json (recieved through post request from mailgun of incoming email).

I'm using codeigniter.

Following is a portion the json that I'm dealing with.

```
 },
"log-level": "info",
"timestamp": 1475215276.814206,
"message": {
"headers": {
  "to": "helpdesk@example.com",
  "message-id": "CALv887xt-=_ijgb1iC0BQcOwJXguOWbiF7j+Licx6kqperh5Zg@mail.gmail.com",
  "from": "User Test <user.test@gmail.com>",
  "subject": "example email for testing"
},
"attachments": [],
"recipients": [
  "53954680dacd5416eedb3f8639ece5f9@email.example.com"
],
```

I do not have any problem accessing the **from** value `$this->input->post('from')` and **subject** value `$this->input->post('subject')`.

However I'm trying to access the **to** and **recipients** with the following code, but all I'm getting is null values.

```
$to = $this->input->post('to');

$message_header = $this->input->post('message');
$recipients = $message_header->recipients;
$email = $recipients[0];
$email_q = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the to address in the following way.

In Codeigniter:

```
$this->input->post('recipient');
```

In PHP:

```
$_POST['recipient'];
```